# Postgresql buffers_alloc

Tags: performance, postgresql, buffer

I am trying to create a performance monitors for postgresql. Inpostgresql  have seen buffers_alloc (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html) and the explanation is "Number of buffers allocated". I tired to find the exact meaning of number of Buffers. Could some one please explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

All data in PostgreSQL is organized in 8KB blocks, on storage as well as in memory.

A buffer is an 8KB block in database shared memory.